# Haskell speed of pre-defined function vs copying source code

Tags: function, haskell

why is that when I use predefined `filter`, it works so much faster than if I use a function which is an exact copy of the [source file from Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#filter)?

so  comparing predefined `filter` with

```
filter1 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter1 _pred []    = []
filter1 pred (x:xs)
  | pred x         = x : filter1 pred xs
  | otherwise      = filter1 pred xs
```

and while we are at it

```
filter2 ::  (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter2 pred  xs = [x | x <- xs, pred x]
```

and

```
filter3 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter3 pred = foldr (\x ys -> if pred x then x : ys else ys) []
```

running `last $ filter odd [1..20000000]` for all gives:

```
*Main> :set +s

*Main> last $ filter odd [1..20000000]
19999999
(**2.42 secs**, 4,716,736,640 bytes)

*Main> last $ filter1 odd [1..20000000]
19999999
(**15.72 secs**, 6,883,675,064 bytes)

*Main> last $ filter2 odd [1..20000000]
19999999
(**13.17 secs**, 5,839,140,920 bytes)

*Main> last $ filter3 odd [1..20000000]
19999999
(**11.09 secs**, 6,486,331,496 bytes)
```

why would `filter1` be different from `filter` (considering `filter1` is the source code) and why is the source code slower than 2 other implementations? (using list comprehensions or `foldr`)

NB there is no purpose the final function. I was just testing the different speeds...

Comment: compiled code vs interpreted

Comment: The base modules contain a heck lot of stream fusion rules. When you run something like `last $ filter odd [1..20000000]`, you may not actually get a list of all numbers from 1 to 20000000, which is then traversed to remove even numbers, which is then traversed to the last element. The compiler is allowed to apply a lot of transformations which it knows won't change the result, but reckons might be more efficient cache/etc.-wise. — But apart from that... as karafka said the reason can be as simple as not having compiled the functions with optimisations. And, how did you obtain those timings?

Comment: @karakfa is that all it is ?  I guess I was wrong in thinking that filter was also interpreted in interpreted or is it just the .hs that is loaded that is is interpreted??

Comment: Be to sure to check out http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is because when you load `MyFilter.hs` directly into GHCi, it is interpreted instead of compiled.

To wit, here are the timings on my machine, using GHC 7.8.3, by loading everything into GHCi:

```
$ ghci-7.8.3 MyFilter.hs
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling MyFilter     ( MyFilter.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: MyFilter.
*MyFilter> let xs = [1..20000000] :: [Int]
*MyFilter> :set +s
*MyFilter> last xs  -- Just to remove any effect of evaluating `xs` itself
20000000
(3.00 secs, 627134572 bytes)
*MyFilter> last $ filter odd xs
19999999
(2.00 secs, 1451220660 bytes)
*MyFilter> last $ filter1 odd xs
19999999
(17.55 secs, 2627102272 bytes)
*MyFilter> last $ filter2 odd xs
19999999
(13.54 secs, 1877989348 bytes)
*MyFilter> last $ filter3 odd xs
19999999
(15.44 secs, 2256212504 bytes)
```

Note especially the `MyFilter.hs, interpreted` line.

Now if we compile it before loading it into GHCi, the timing numbers between `filter` and `filter1`/`filter2`/`filter3` suddenly line up:

```
$ ghc-7.8.3 --make MyFilter.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling MyFilter     ( MyFilter.hs, MyFilter.o )
$ ghci-7.8.3 MyFilter.hs
GHCi, version 7.8.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Ok, modules loaded: MyFilter.
Prelude MyFilter> let xs = [1..20000000] :: [Int]
Prelude MyFilter> :set +s
Prelude MyFilter> last xs
20000000
(2.84 secs, 710745024 bytes)
Prelude MyFilter> last $ filter odd xs
19999999
(2.07 secs, 1374513668 bytes)
Prelude MyFilter> last $ filter1 odd xs
19999999
(2.07 secs, 1499566524 bytes)
Prelude MyFilter> last $ filter2 odd xs
19999999
(2.12 secs, 1499505652 bytes)
Prelude MyFilter> last $ filter3 odd xs
19999999
(2.26 secs, 1500830732 bytes)
```

Comment: In 7.10, at least, `last` is defined as a fold, so it should fuse with `filter`. The enumeration passed to filter is defined, ultimately, using `build`, so it will fuse with `filter` too. None of this will happen without the appropriate `RULES` in the list library.

Comment: @dfeuer: can we still agree that the largest effect that @matthias saw was because of `filter1`/`filter2`/`filter3` being interpreted?

Comment: In GHCi, that's true, since fusion doesn't happen there.